# Does dataframe.repartition(x) makes execution faster

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have a Spark script that reads data from amazon S3 and then writes in another bucket usion parquet format.

This is what the code looks like:

```
File = "LocationInFirstBucket.csv.gz"
df_ods = spark.read.csv(File, header=True, sep=";")

df_ods.repartition(25).write.format("parquet").mode("OverWrite").save("AnotherLocationInS3")
```

My question is: how does the repartition argument (here 25) affects the execution time? Should I increase it so the script runs faster?

Second question: Would it be better if I cache my df before the last line?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical setups neither repartition nor cache will help you in this specific case. Since you read data from non-splittable format:

> ```
> File = "LocationInFirstBucket.csv.gz"
> df_ods = spark.read.csv(File, header=True, sep=";")
> ```

`df_ods` will have only one partition.

In such case repartitioning would make sense, if you performed any actual processing on this data.

However if you just write to distributed file system repartitioning will simply double the cost - you have to send data to other nodes first (that involves serialization, deserialization, network transfer, write to disk) and then still write to distributed file system.

There are of course edge cases when this makes sense. If network connecting your cluster is much faster than network connection your cluster to S3 nodes, effective latency might be a bit lower.

As of caching ‒ there is no value in caching here at all. Caching Dataset is expensive, and makes sense only if persisted data is reused.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. What options do I have if I absolutely need to reduce execution time then? Should I have df_ods partitioned while reading it? If yes, how can that be done please?

Comment: Short of not using gz in the first place? It might be slightly faster to unpack data first, but you'd have to benchmark it on your own setup.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 :- Repartition of 25 or more or less it depends on how much data you have and no. of executors you provided. If your Spark code run in the cluster with more than one executor and it is not repartitioned then repartitioning will speedy to writing parallel your data.

Answer 2 :- There is no need to cache df before the last line because you are using only single action in your code. If you will perform multiple actions on your DF and don't want it will recalculate as the number of actions then you will Cache it.

Comment: Writing a file does indeed depend on the number of partitions and executors provided. I invite you to try it with any dataset in a cluster a see what happens.

Comment: Obviously, if you have 10 partitions file and 50 executors in that case 40 executors will be ideal. you can try it.

Answer (score -1):

The thing here is that Spark can parallelize writing to a certain point since one file can't be written by multiple executors at the same time.

Repartition helps you in this parallelization because it will write 25 different files (one for each partition). If you increase the number of partitions you will increase the number of written files hence speeding up the execution. This comes with a price because of the reading time will increase with the number of files to be read.

The limit is the number of executors you are running your job with, e.g. if you are running with 25 executors then setting repartition to 26 will not help you because to write the 26th partition one of the previous 25 would have to be finished.

For the other question, I don't think .cache() will help you because Spark is lazy, maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@gaga19900329/force-caching-spark-dataframes-84d32730a21) can help you further.